# Mysql - how to check id and date order

Tags: mysql, date, filter

I have a table with 3 columns :

1. id  (auto incremental)
2. group_id
3. date

Theoretically for a same group_id the date for an id would be greater than the last inserted one.

For example :

1. | group5 | 2016-06-28
2. | group9 | 2016-05-01
3. | group9 | 2016-05-10
4. | group5 | 2016-06-29
5. | group9 | 2016-05-12

So if I select group5 it would be :

1. | group5 | 2016-06-28
2. | group5 | 2016-06-29

But I had issue in inserting date, and I would like to filter only rows where 
date and id for a same group aren't ascended.

For example :

1. | group5 | 2016-06-28
2. | group9 | 2016-05-01
3. | group9 | 2016-05-10
4. | group5 | 2016-06-29
5. | group9 | 2016-05-09

The issue is that for group9 id 3 is 2016-05-10 and next id (5) has a date lower (2016-05-09)

Is it possible to make an sql to filter that ?
Regards

Comment: Where is your query? Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you trying to fix the order the rows were created in or just select data put of this table in date order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
select 1.* from my_table as 1, my_table as 2 
where 1.group_id = 2.group_id and 1.id > 2.id and 1.date < 2.date
```